# jquery.i18n.properties not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem using this jQuery internationalization. I added the `jquery.i18n.properties.js`, `jquery.i18n.properties-min.js`, and `jquery-min.js` files to my resources folder.

In my jsp I added this file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-min.js/>"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.i18n.properties.js" />"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.i18n.properties-min.js" />"></script>
```

Then in the JS file I'm trying to load the .properties file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'Messages',
        path:'webapp/WEB-INF/messageSources/',
        mode:'both',
        language:'en',
        callback: function() {
            alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('registration.field.empty'));
        }
    });
```

but it prints out the key ('registration.field.empty') as a message instead of the value.

My property file is: Messages_en.properties

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your `jsp` you have this:

```
<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-min.js/>"
```

But it needs to be this:

```
<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-min.js" />
```

You just made a typo... and I'm not familiar with jsp but don't you have to escape the double quotes with `\` before each one?

Comment: Sorry for this, it seems that I have made this typo when paste the code. In my code, this is correct.

Comment: What HTML gets output after the `jsp` is done running?

Comment: What do you mean, html gets output? My goal is to use Message_en.properties file in one js file. In the jsp page that I'm loading I add this tree urls and I expect to load them when I typed this in the js file. But its not happening. It alert out the key instead of the value

Comment: am facing same issue. It seems that property files from 'webapp/WEB-INF/messageSources/' path can not be added in this way. I tried with "","/","/messageSources/" and all possible, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the WEB-INF directory is restricted to be accessed from outside of the servlet-context. And javascript is definitely out of the servlet-context.

You need to copy your MessageResouces-files (language-files/properties) from WEB-INF into another directory,...

1. e.g. create directory /i18n (on the same level as WEB-INF, but not inside WEB-INF!)
2. Put properties files into the created directory
3. Retry to access the files